# c program freeze when trying to create another child process

Tags: c, fork

My original code is too long to post so let me try to write a simple version

```
//this commands() function will be called multiple times
int commands()
  {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid<0)
    {
      printf("Failed to open child process\n");
      return -1;
    }

    if(pid == 0)
    {
      //we are in child
      child_function(); // calls some function to do some work
      //note that this function end up calling execvp() so it never comes back  
    }
    else
    {
      int status=0;
      int_returned_pid = waitpid(-1, &status,0);

      if(status !=0)
        return 1;
      else
        return 0;
    }

  }
```

so what happens is, when the program calls commands first time, it successfully creates a child, child process finishes and command returns.
But when commands function is called second time, again child is successfully created and child_function() is called. after this, the program just stops and it feels like its waiting for input or someting (it does not crash).

After spending several hours here, I have no idea what is the problem, Please help.

Edit: I am using pipes in my program and basically when commands function is called the first time, I need its children to read someting from stdin, do some stuff and then write to pipe. And then upon calling commands function second time, i need its children to read from that pipe that the 1st call children wrote to and then to write to stdout.

Do I need to close these pipes in a parent process ?

Comment: "it feels like". No need to guess. What does your debugger tell you the program is doing? Even a few debugging `printf` statements would likely tell you that information.

Comment: fair enoguh, after commands function is called 2nd time and the child_function() is called, the program just hangs after calling execvp().

Comment: Which program hangs? The parent or the child? Because `execvp` is called by the child not the parent. But it sounds like you are saying the parent hangs. If it is indeed the parent you are looking at then it is likely blocked on `waitpid` in which case you need to look at what the program being invoked by `execvp` is doing - does it indeed exit?

Comment: "Do I need to close these pipes in a parent process". Well yes, eventually. And so does the child. If you don't close it properly and at the right time, this can cause `read` calls to block indefinetely. Whether this is the cause of your problem or not cannot be stated for certain unless you show the `pipe` and `read/write` code. It's clear now that you are not providing all the relevant information. Please take a time out now and form a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that for us.

Comment: kaylum, you are absolutley correct, I did not provide the full info because I was thinking it is irrelevant. But now, I see that it was more than relevant. I believe not closing the pipes was exacly my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Just FYI, the general rule is that after `fork`, each process should immediately close off the end of the pipe that it will not use. That is, the process that writes should close the read end of the pipe and vice versa.

Comment: And if parent is not using either end of the pipe, close both ends right away in parent as well correct ?

Comment: Yes, but after the parent has finished all its `fork` calls of course (ie, after the second `fork` and not the first one in your example).

Comment: nice, just one more question, since both children are created in different calls to commands function, instead of closing the file descriptors in that function should I just close them in function that calls commands ?

Comment: Without seeing the code I couldn't say for sure. But it does sound like a better place to do it as the `commands` function really shouldn't need to know whether it is being called for the first or second time.

Comment: @Kaylum, It would be cool if you could write up your advice all together in one "answer" post, it's good stuff.